# How can I calculate future dates in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, date, discord, bots, discord.js

So I have giveaway bot and you have to write how long the giveaway should be last p.E. 2d (two days).
My bot will then convert it into milliseconds, 2 days -> 172800000 ms. I can also read the currently date out, but I don't know how I could calculate the end of the giveaway ( it should be a normal date, nothing in milliseconds). Thanks for answers !

Comment: Just add, the required time to your date in milliseconds, then use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) to convert it back to a proper string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just convert your date to ms (I'm using the `.valueOf()`-function), add the desired ms (in your case 172800000) and reconvert it to a date using `new Date(/*some ms value here*/)`

```js
const now = new Date();

const inTwoDays = now.valueOf() + 172800000;

console.log("start date:", now);
console.log("end date:", new Date(inTwoDays));
```